# Can I make a bridge without liquidity?

Tags: network, liquidity-provider, swaps, bridge

I started developing what it meant to be a bridge to learn and settle down my Solidity knowledge. I thought it could be done by one person and from what I understood I just needed smart contracts to burn and mint in several networks. However, I realized I need to actually have liquidity, so when I burn in one network I can mint in the other one. For example, if I burn ETH in the mainnet, I need liquidity to mint Wrapped ETH in MATIC network.

Is there a way to make a bridge or swap project without having real liquidity? I just wanted to make a real production site that could be done by one person without much money at hand.

p.s. I am still learning so I might have misconceptions

Thank you in advance and regards